# Is it possible to create a table with a partition by x (sequence_number) where the dbms automatically define the difference sequence_numberS?

Tags: sql, oracle12c, partitioning

Is it possible to create a table with a partition by x (sequence_number) where the dbms automatically define the difference sequence_numberS? And if so, how? :)

I know the data will contain of different sequence numbers, but I don't know what the difference will be between the different sequence numbers (at least must be a delta of 1, can also be a delta of 999). The difference will not be static, so setting it to interval (1) will not work I guess.

PS: I stated 'partition by x', where x is range, or hash, or whatever. PS2: I'm using Oracle 12.

Does anyone know of a trick to retrieve an automated interval, or something?

I think of something like:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_x"  ( "SEQUENCE_NUMBER" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
                         ,"VALUE1" VARCHAR2(36 CHAR)
                         ,"VALUE2" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE ) 
partition by range(SEQUENCE_NUMBER)
interval (automatic value);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: what do you mean with a trigger? If I can add it, that will be the trick

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one can use partition by range with interval=1, even if the difference with the previous sequence_number is higher than 1. So I made a wrong assumption. My bad.

There is a downfall by the way, and that is that Oracle accepts a maximum of 1048575 subpartitions. So in my case where I will have sequence_number's passing the treshold of 1048575, one would have to make some other method to get a derived number for making subpartitions. I thought of a way and that is to generate my own derived sequence number (in another log table) where there is place for 48 iterations and after 48 iterations the sequence numbers will be reused and in that way the maximum number of subpartitions will be 48. Anyways.

The creation script I used was this and that works:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_x"  ( "SEQUENCE_NUMBER" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
                             ,"VALUE1" VARCHAR2(36 CHAR)
                             ,"VALUE2" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE)
ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED 
STORAGE(
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "STOD" 
PARTITION BY RANGE ("SEQUENCE_NUMBER") INTERVAL (1) 
(PARTITION "P1"  VALUES LESS THAN (1) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED LOGGING 
STORAGE(
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "STOD" ) 
PARALLEL  ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```